# IntelliJ can't find dependencies tab

Tags: java, intellij-idea

[image: project structure] I'm using IntelliJ to make a webshop for school. I need to add the dependency `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore` but when i go to **Project structure > Modules**, I don't have the dependecies tab. Anyone who can help?

Comment: What's your build tool? Maven?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It might be helpful if you share screenshots...

Comment: Make sure you have created the module of a Java type - it has a Dependency tab.

Comment: Not with maven no

Comment: May I suggest that you remove the module and create a new one? (make a copy of your source code first, obviously ;) )

Comment: Thanks that worked!

Answer (score 0):

Go to -- File | Project Structure | Modules |, you will find a dependency tab.

Comment: I know but the dependency tab is nog there

Comment: I dont see a SDK to the project. Have you created the module of java?

Comment: I think so, tho i am not sure. How can i check/do it?

Comment: Just make a new one.